# Маршрут с параметрами в Angular выдает 404

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Проект на Angular 13.

описание маршрута

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'my-path/:my-param',
        component: MyComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

а здесь переход на него

```
this.router.navigate(['my-path'], { queryParams: { my-param: 'value' } });
```

В итоге меня выкидывает на страницу 404.

Где у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо исправить переход:

```
this.router.navigate(['my-path', 'value']);
```

Так как в строке `path: 'my-path/:my-param'` параметр `:my-param` это не queryParams.